# How to broadcast an event down to an element from rootScope in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

For example, we have root scope

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <div id="element-on-branch"></div>
    <my-element></my-element>
</template>
```

Then  fires an event

```
this.fire('custom')
```

It goes to root and then I need to route this event to . How can I broadcast an event or notify branched elements?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [iron-signals](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals).

Fire an iron signal event inside your element:

```
this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'mysignal', data: "data"});
```

Then listen to that signal **from anywhere in your webapp** using an iron-signals element.

```
...
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-mysignal="_handleEvent"></iron-signals>
```

Comment: Great answer, love iron-signals!

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/communication.html here is solution for my dumb question)

Comment: Article link above is for an older version of Polymer but is still a good guide.