# Polymer 1.0: How to pass an event to a child-node element without using <iron-signals>?

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events, polymer-1.0

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32590511/1640892) suggests using `<iron-signals>` to broadcast an event down the DOM tree to a custom element.

Below, I ask a different question.

## Question

> How do I:

> - pass an event down to a **direct child** node (custom element)
> - from a parent (custom element)
> - **without using `<iron-signals>`**?

### Code

This is what I have so far. But it doesn't work.

parent-element.html

```
<dom-module id="parenet-element">   
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <child-element></child-element>
    <paper-button on-tap="_handleTap"></paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'parenet-element',
      _handleTap: function() {
        this.fire("my-event");
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

child-element.html

```
<dom-module id="child-element"> 
...
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',
      listeners: {
        "my-event": "foo"
      },
      foo: function(){
        // Do stuff
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You definitely can. Without `iron-signals` you've got three options (that I currently know of):

1. Get the parent and have the child attach an event listener to the parent
2. The parent can have the child fire the same event
3. You mentioned that events only go up. You can then make the child element listen to the `document` firing that event (but I think this is bad)

Here's an example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="parent-element">
    <template>
      <child-element></child-element>
      <button id="btn" on-tap="_fireParentEvent1">Fire 1!</button>
      <button id="btn" on-tap="_fireParentEvent2">Fire 2!</button>
      <button id="btn" on-tap="_fireParentEvent3">Fire 3!</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="child-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <span id="changeMe">Message</span>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <parent-element></parent-element>
  <script>
    (function registerElements() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'parent-element',
        listeners: {
          'event-two': '_attachToChild'
        },
        _attachToChild: function(e) {
          // the parent makes the child fire an event
          var childElement = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('child-element');
          childElement.fire('event-two', e.detail);
        },
        _fireParentEvent1: function(e) {
          // the parent fires an event
          this.fire('event-one', {
            message: 'hello'
          });
        },
        _fireParentEvent2: function(e) {
          this.fire('event-two', {
            message: 'goodbye'
          });
        },
        _fireParentEvent3: function(e) {
          // the parent fires an event
          this.fire('event-three', {
            message: 'game over'
          });
        }
      });

      Polymer({
        is: 'child-element',
        listeners: {
          'event-two': '_handleEventTwo'
        },
        ready: function() {
          var parent = this.parentNode;

          // the child listens to the parent's event
          parent.addEventListener('event-one', function(e) {
            this.$.changeMe.innerHTML = e.detail.message;
          }.bind(this));

          // listen to the document level event (since events travel up)
          // but this option is difficult to control
          document.addEventListener('event-three', function(e) {
            this.$.changeMe.innerHTML = e.detail.message;
          }.bind(this));
        },
        _handleEventTwo: function(e) {
          this.$.changeMe.innerHTML = e.detail.message;
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

With Polymer 1.2.4 as documented [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html) we can use `fire` method options and force a child node (while still inside a parent element) to fire (and listen first of course) an event:

```
this.fire('test', {
    user: {
        name: 'Marios',
        gender: 'male'
    }
}, {
    node: Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('my-child-element'),
    bubbles: false
});
```

We fired a custom event from an element but the emitter is the `my-child-element` so in there we can attach a listener in the `listeners` object. We also prevent the event bubbling so this event won't move upwards following the parents elements path. A typical listener could be:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-child-element',

    properties: {
        ...
    },
    listeners: {
        'test': '_myHandler'
    },
    _myHandler: function(e) {
        var user = e.detail.user;
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: this works but what if there is a dom-repeat attached to the `child-element`? for example, 
`<dom-module id="parent-element">`
          `<template is="dom-repeat" it>`
               `<child-element></child-element>`
        `</template>`
`</dom-module>`
in this situation, the `querySelector` will just fire the event for first element that it matches, and `querySelectorAll` will fire the event for all items at once. I want one at a time. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

@arthur in the Polymer Slack site says:

> Events tend to go ***up*** the DOM tree. Going down, you can use a data binding or invoke a method.

[Polymer Slack Site](https://polymer.slack.com/messages/general/)

Comment: Can't access the link attached, could you paste any example if he has provided one. Thanks!